# JDEPS Module Not Found Exception when listing dependancies

Tags: java, jar, java-11, java-14, jdeps

I have been working with JLink to create minimal JRE for various Spring Boot applications. I have successfully done this manually by figuring out the required Modules via trial and error. After successfully doing this I have been attempting to automate this process using JDeps.

First attempt was to scan the built Jar for my application. I am using Java 14 jdeps to analyze a Java 11 codebase.

`jdeps --class-path BOOT-INF/classes --module-path BOOT-INF/lib/,${JAVA_HOME}/jmods --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --list-deps  target/camel-account-sapi-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Which results in several not found dependencies.

```
Error: Missing dependencies: classes not found from the module path and classpath.
To suppress this error, use --ignore-missing-deps to continue.

camel-account-sapi-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.CamelAccountSapiApplication -> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication         not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.CamelAccountSapiApplication -> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.CamelAccountSapiApplication -> org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.GeneratedRoutesInterface -> org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder              not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.GeneratedRoutesInterface -> org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestDefinition         not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.GeneratedRoutesInterface -> org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestOperationParamDefinition not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.GeneratedRoutesInterface -> org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType          not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.GeneratedRoutesInterface -> org.springframework.stereotype.Component           not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> com.datasonnet.document.MediaTypes                 not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.Exchange                          not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.Expression                        not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel                      not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.Predicate                         not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.builder.DatasonnetBuilder         not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder              not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder             not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder              not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.model.ChoiceDefinition            not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.model.OnExceptionDefinition       not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition         not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition             not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.slf4j.Logger                                   not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory                            not found
   com.ms3.camelaccountsapi.routes.RoutesImplementation -> org.springframework.stereotype.Component           not found
   org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher -> org.springframework.util.Assert                    not found
   org.springframework.boot.loader.jarmode.JarModeLauncher -> org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader not found
   org.springframework.boot.loader.jarmode.JarModeLauncher -> org.springframework.util.ClassUtils                not found
```

Adding `--ignore-missing-deps` results in something more meaning full but incomplete:

```
java.base
java.logging
```

Next I extracted the applications using `java -Djarmode=layertools -jar ./target/camel-account-sapi-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar extract`

This gives me the BOOT-INF/lib folder containing all 150 of the JAR dependancies. So I attempted to run a similar JDeps command as before with a few extra options:
`jdeps --module-path temp/BOOT-INF/lib/,${JAVA_HOME}/jmods --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --multi-release 11 --list-deps --ignore-missing-deps --recursive --compile-time  temp/BOOT-INF/lib/*`

This however results in an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.annotation not found, required by org.apache.tomcat.embed.core
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:894)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:422)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:256)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

I noticed that some of the JARs in the /lib folder could successfully be analyzed so I wrote a Bash script to run the same command on each of the /lib jars while ignoring exceptions. 15 of the 150 fail to be analyzed due to `Module not found` however the resulting list of required Modules from the other 135 is quite close. It is only missing one required Module `jdk.crypto.ec` and found all others:

`java.sql,java.security.jgss,java.logging,java.xml,java.compiler,jdk.unsupported,java.transaction.xa,java.rmi,java.management,java.instrument,java.naming,java.base,java.datatransfer,jdk.httpserver,java.scripting,java.desktop,java.prefs`

Am I going in the wrong direction? Or what could/should be done to resolved these missing Module issues? I believe, for example that the "Missing" module above `java.annotation` may exist in one of the other JARs? I believe this to be the case even more so due to a few of the other 15 failed jdeps commands.

```
temp/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.annotation not found, required by org.apache.tomcat.embed.core
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:894)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:422)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:256)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
error
temp/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.apache.tomcat.embed.core not found, required by org.apache.tomcat.embed.websocket
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:894)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:422)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:256)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
error
```

Comment: Same problem here... I'm the author of UnmazedBoot and I'm looking at the command to automate a Linker docker image that generates the custom JRE for any SpringBoot application... jdeps only returns the 2 modules you listed above... :( https://medium.com/@marcellodesales/unmazedboot-generic-springboot-docker-images-to-build-link-run-your-application-in-seconds-3e30c3ee6fe6

Comment: can you share the script you created to collect all the values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through a very similar issue right now. It looks like between tomcat embed 9.0.37 and 9.0.38 explicit module-info's were defined.  The names of modules changed compared to automatic modules.

- `java.annotation` module is the name exported from the annotations-api.jar. I have no idea why it uses that name. I'm sure there is a reason, I just don't understand it.
- `org.apache.tomcat.embed.jasper.el` changed to `org.apache.tomcat.embed.el`

I'm not sure how far that's going to get you, but it's perhaps a start.

Comment: I'm currently stuck starting my embed tomcat with my minimal JRE made with jlink.  I'm getting a FindException. `java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.management.rmi not found, required by org.apache.tomcat.embed.core`.